# Problem in adding a footnote

Tags: footnotes

I fails to make a footnote with my code even if I add `In this paper\footnote{This note is written...............}, we aim`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
   %---------- To move the authors addresses to the footnote ----------

   \makeatletter

 \patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\scshape\ignorespaces}{\ignorespaces}{}{} % addresses in lowercase

\appto\maketitle{%
\let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax
\ifx\@empty\addresses\else\@footnotetext{%
  \vskip-\bigskipamount\@setaddresses}
  }
\def\enddoc@text{}
\makeatother

%-----------------------end -------------------
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}
  {\the\toks@}
  {}
  {}{}
%----titre lowercase-----------
\patchcmd\@settitle{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{\Large}{}{}
%\patchcmd\@settitle{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{} {}{}
%-------------------------
\patchcmd\@setauthors
  {\MakeUppercase{\authors}}
  {\authors}
  {}{}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%-----------------              
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% hyperref %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red , linkcolor= blue}
%----------
%\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}      % \labelcref pour les equations
%----------
%%%%%%%%%%%% \begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%------------------------
\address{$^{[1]}$ Author's Adress.}
\email{\url{....@....com}}

\keywords{keywords, ......}

\date{\today}

\author[Author] {\Large{Author}$^{1}$}
\title[Title]{Title}

\maketitle
%------------------------
%----------\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{abstract}
In this paper\footnote{This note is written...............}, we aim 
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Footnotes do not belong in the abstract. Also, according to the documentation, the abstract has to come *before* `\maketitle`, cf. http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/amscls-doc/Author_Handbook_Journals.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working around the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
   %---------- To move the authors addresses to the footnote ----------

   \makeatletter

 \patchcmd{\@setaddresses}{\scshape\ignorespaces}{\ignorespaces}{}{} % addresses in lowercase

\appto\maketitle{%
\let\@makefnmark\relax  \let\@thefnmark\relax
\ifx\@empty\addresses\else\@footnotetext{%
  \vskip-\bigskipamount\@setaddresses}
  }
\def\enddoc@text{}
\makeatother

%-----------------------end -------------------
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\uppercasenonmath\shorttitle}
  {}
  {}{}
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {\@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}
  {\the\toks@}
  {}
  {}{}
%----titre lowercase-----------
\patchcmd\@settitle{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{\Large}{}{}
%\patchcmd\@settitle{\uppercasenonmath\@title}{} {}{}
%-------------------------
\patchcmd\@setauthors
  {\MakeUppercase{\authors}}
  {\authors}
  {}{}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------------------
%\usepackage[notref,notcite]{showkeys}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
%-----------------              
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% hyperref %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red , linkcolor= blue}
%----------
%\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}      % \labelcref pour les equations
%----------
%%%%%%%%%%%% \begin{document} %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%------------------------
\address{$^{[1]}$ Author's Adress.}
\email{\url{....@....com}}

\keywords{keywords, ......}

\date{\today}

\author[Author] {\Large{Author}$^{1}$}
\title[Title]{Title}


%------------------------
%----------\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{abstract}
In this paper\footnotemark[1], we aim 
\end{abstract}

{\maketitle}

\footnotetext[1]{This note is written...............}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
text\footnote{text}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice workaround. But don't do it.